# iOS background images - best practice for supporting all display heights

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimageview, background-image

What is the best practice for supporting iOS devices of different display heights when implementing background images?

**DETAIL:**

I'm updating an iOS app with numerous background images. The background image used is either too short for a 4-inch display (iPhone 5) or too large for a 3.5-inch display (iPhone 4S).

Is there a way to have iOS automatically determine the correct background image to use depending on the device display height (perhaps through auto layout+constraints or image file name?) or is my only option to check the screen size in code and then apply the appropriate background image?

Comment: You could use the same BG image and have just a little extra of the BG show for the 5.  Otherwise, you seem to know what to do ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you referring to launch images? If yes, then you can define different names for different images.

If you are referring to background images for some activities, then you have a couple of options:

1. Create a separate background for different phone sizes and check the height of the phone in the code.
2. Create a background for a bigger iPhone and let the smaller iPhone to automatically crop it.

No, there is no way for phone to determine the right image resource depending on the name or the auto layout constraints.